# pk-debconf-helper process loads a single processor core at 100% after each update. Opting out?

Tags: package-management, 20.04, dpkg, fan

On Ubuntu 20.04.2, with Gnome desktop.

Recently, each time the software updater finishes with the updates, the `pk-debconf-helper` process kicks in, and keeps loading a single processor core (out of eight cores) at 100% for some time, resulting in the highest fan speeds my laptop sees these days.

I am not a fan of this occurrence, so I would like to know:

- how bad would be the consequences of opting out of what `pk-debconf-helper` does,
- is it possible to opt out somehow?

Comment: I just saw this happen on my 21.10  although it finished after a few seconds .. I heard my fan kick in though ... have not seen this on any of my 20.04 laptops / desk

Comment: This seems to be https://github.com/PackageKit/PackageKit/issues/452, b.t.w..